# justifying text in two columns with display: flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What's the best way to position items in two columns, each of which has `display:flex`? I'm coming across the problem that when the text wraps everything below it moves out of alignment. I'm fairly sure this wouldn't happen if I just used a grid, and I could alternatively position the text absolutely - but is there a better practice? Am I looking at this completely wrong?

```
--------------------   --------------------
        image                  image

      a header              a header 
                        that wraps at this 
                               size  

                           some content

 content that doesn't
   line up any more
```

justifying with space-around / space-between and using flex-grow doesn't get the desired effect because the available space is different in each column when the text wraps.

i guess i can just `justify:flex-start;` and then set the margin-top of each item to allow enough space?

here's a codepen of the problem. sorry if it's obvious, i'm pretty new to all this and have tried!

https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/ZxLWPO?editors=1100

Comment: How dynamic do you need it to be? If it's going to be pretty static you can simply specify the height of the `h2` to be the height it is when there's 2 lines, alternatively you could put a break(`<br/>`) in the `h2` that is only one line: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmgozE?editors=1100

Comment: yeah, probably not that dynamic as the containing grid will be shifting the columns about, it was just to deal with the odd text wrapping at smaller sizes. is that seen as the easiest/best way? or just one of many? is absolute positioning within the column not recommended? thanks for those two ways though - does the job nicely

Comment: actually - thinking about it, this is just a small section of what I'm after - at larger sizes I may have 5 columns. i'm guessing line breaks may become more difficult, but the line height idea might still work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you want to 'center-align' the heading and the contents once it wraps.

For which, you may set a `text-align` center to both `<p>` and `<h2>` and also specify a width if you want the wrapping to happen after a specific limit.

```
.icon-card > p,
.icon-card > h2 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px; /* Optional */
}
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/gegqEB)

Hope this helps.